# destory session after one hour in javascript

Tags: javascript

This code is working when the user visit the site it gives a pupup form only onces ,here the cookies is save in browser and when the same user is visit site again he is not getting the pupup form again ,i want that when the same user visit site next day the cookies should clear automatically
after 12 o'clock(mid night)
here is my code

```js
  function PopUp(hideOrshow) {
        if (hideOrshow == 'hide') {
            document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display = "none";
        }
        else  if(localStorage.getItem("popupWasShown") == null) {
            localStorage.setItem("popupWasShown",1);
            document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').removeAttribute('style');
        }
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            PopUp('show');
        }, 0);
    }


    function hideNow(e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'ac-wrapper') document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display = 'none';
    }
```

```css
#ac-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("images/pop-bg.png") repeat top left transparent;
    z-index: 1001;
}
#popup {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 18px;
    -moz-border-radius: 18px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 18px;
    height: 361px;
    margin: 5% auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 597px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ac-wrapper" style='display:none' onClick="hideNow(event)">
    <div id="popup">
        <center>
             <h2>Popup Content Here</h2> 
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="PopUp('hide')" />
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So it check if cookie exist on window onload and then it's hide it onclick, and the cookie expire at midnight

```
 function hideNow() {
        document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display = 'none';
        setCookie('show_cookie_message','no');
        return false;
    }
    window.onload = function () {

        if(getCookie('show_cookie_message') != 'no')
        {
            document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').removeAttribute('style');
        }
    }

function setCookie(cookie_name, value)
{
    var now = new Date();
    var expire = new Date();
    expire.setFullYear(now.getFullYear());
    expire.setMonth(now.getMonth());
    expire.setDate(now.getDate()+1);
    expire.setHours(0);
    expire.setMinutes(0);
    document.cookie = cookie_name + "=" + escape(value) + "; expires="+expire.toUTCString() + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(cookie_name)
{
    if (document.cookie.length>0)
    {
        cookie_start = document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_name + "=");
        if (cookie_start != -1)
        {
            cookie_start = cookie_start + cookie_name.length+1;
            cookie_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";",cookie_start);
            if (cookie_end == -1)
            {
                cookie_end = document.cookie.length;
            }
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(cookie_start,cookie_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

```
<div id="ac-wrapper" style='display:none' >
    <div id="popup">
        <center>
             <h2>Popup Content Here</h2> 
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="hideNow()" />
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @kumar123  you welcome. can you please mark answer as valid and up-vote.